# Ripple Cordova Chrome "aw snap" message when plugin Media is part of the project

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-chrome, ripple

I use Ripple as it is explained in this article (http://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/11/05/Ripple-is-Reborn/), and until Feb the 1st 2016, it was working really well.

I run on: windows 8, Chrome:Version 48.0.2564.97 m, Ripple 0.9.32, cordova 4.0.0 (which carries cordova android 3.6.4).

I had several plugins installed on my project, among them Media (apache.org.cordova.media). Until the beginning of this week it was functioning just fine and suddenly I got the the "Aw, Snap!" page crashes message when I was loading my project thru Ripple and Chrome (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95669?hl=en), support advice from google weren't helpful.

In order to figure out why it wasn't suddenly working, I created a 'HelloWorld' Cordova project with CLI: "cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld".

I ran it in Ripple/Chrome and it worked (no "Aw, Snap!" message).

Then I've tried to add regular cordova plugins to it like:
"cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file", etc.

Thru the tests, I noticed that the **Ripple/Chrome would work correctly except when the plugin org.apache.cordova.media was on**. And that was in that case that the **"Aw, Snap!" message** would be delivered by Chrome.

Then I focus my analysis on why that plugin would be a source of trouble. I reached the following conclusion: **The Cordova JavaScript function/object "MediaError" that is carried by "MediaError.js" is in conflict with another MediaError function that can be used in JavaScript under Chrome.**

So I found a workaround to it -a clumsy solution unfortunately-. Under "[cordova_project_name]\platforms\android\assets\www", I edited the file "cordova_plugin.js" and put in comment the block concerning MediaError:

```
    /*{
    "file": "plugins/org.apache.cordova.media/www/MediaError.js",
    "id": "org.apache.cordova.media.MediaError",
    "clobbers": [
        "window.MediaError"
    ]
},*/
```

Then finally: no more "Aw, Snap!" message from Ripple/Chrome, but no more cordova MediaError function neither. If one could help me to trick Chrome and tell me **how I could allow, all cordova Javascript functions to override any other javascript functions with similar names** (and then bypass the  "Aw, Snap!" message)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for posting out your research result, It saved me a lot of time!
I don't think you really can fix Chrome. It's better to post it like bug/request and wait. Until then you can simply use older Chrome version for debug as I end up doing.
You can download older chrome version from here: http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-chrome-46-0-2490-80-enterprise-version

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in the Chrome, which was reported by the MS Team.

So here are the two ways to get around this issue, till chrome fixes it or MS team come up with better solution

1. In Visual Studio, click Tools -> Options
2. Find the Tools for Apache
3. Cordova Click the “Clear Cordova Cache” button
4. Rebuild your project

or

1. Open a command prompt
2. cd %AppData%\npm\node_modules\vs-tac
3. npm update ripple-emulator

Here is the Official [Post](http://microsoft.github.io/vstacoblog/2016/02/12/update-to-ripple.html) by MSTeam. To track this bug which was reported in chromium ,please refer [this link](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=585260)

Comment: HI @Webruster, thank you for your feedback but since I am not using VS, I had no need for it. Also yesterday I've updated to Chrome 50.0.2661.75. And the "aw snapp" message with ripple is back (I ve opened a new question  about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36699614/ripple-broken-with-chrome-version-50-0-2661-75-aw-snapp-error-message). Have you experienced the same issue with the new Chrome as well?