# Ripple broken with Chrome version 50.0.2661.75 - "aw snapp" error message

Tags: cordova, google-chrome, chromium, ripple

Apache-Ripple was working correctly until chrome updated to version 50.0.2661.75 m.

I use ripple not as a chrome-extension but as explained in this article:https://www.raymondcamden.com/2013/11/05/Ripple-is-Reborn/

If I try with an empty Cordova project, I get the "aw snap" message. In the development console I can see that "XHR and Fetch" are going wrong for "user-agent" (status code 500) and "config.xml" (status code 404). I do get those messages as well if I run same Cordova/Ripple project in IE (MS Edge 25.10586.0.0): So it fails but it is normal, because in IE Ripple works (but since I need WebSQL IE is not enough).

I did a flush of all cache info in Chrome and computer restart... It did not help.

If anyone find a way around, I'd be grateful to know how. Or -if Ripple is too deprecated to survive Chrome's updates- let me know suggestions of newer tools to test Cordova hybrid app.

Comment: @nylue are you using any plugins? and i am loading my url with `loadUrlTimeoutValue` so that my app is opening in chrome after update

Comment: @Webruster I use no plugins, I get the error with a brand new (and empty) cordova project. I don't know about "loadUrlTimeoutValue", I'll look into that -Do you have any specific tutorial/doc about it, you'd recommend?.

Comment: @Webstruter I added     <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="10000"/> to the config.xml under [cordova_project]\, then I built the project, went to  [cordova_project]\platforms\android\assets\www, run 'ripple emulate', went on Chrome and still get the 'aw snapp' message. I am a bit confuse with your hint: loadUrlTimeoutValue since it seems to apply on the java side of the android app and I believed that  ripple was only looking at the javascript files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ve reported the error to chrome, they gave me the feedback that it was fixed and will be available in the version 51.

Meanwhile, here is the workaround I found to run Ripple/Cordova:

I've installed Opera (version 36.0.2130.66). Opera does feature WebSQL which was the important thing I needed.